# Django formset rendering 3 formsets

Tags: python, django

I've made a formset that will update a model Client and a model ClientData,my problem is that instead of rendering a formset, it renders it 3 times and i can't identify why.

**views.py**

```
def client_data(request):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ClientForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            client = form.save(commit=False)
            formset = ClientFormSet(request.POST, instance=client)
            if formset.is_valid():
                client.save()
                formset.save()
                return redirect(reverse_lazy('core:index'))
    else:
        form = ClientForm()
        formset = ClientFormSet()
    data['form'] = form
    data['formset'] = formset
    return render(request, 'core/test.html', data)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ClientForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['user', ]


class ClientDataForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ClientData
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['client', ]


ClientFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Client, ClientData, fields=[
    'language',
    'type',
])
```

template

```
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {{ formset }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You build your formset with **inlineformset_factory**, according to the documentation, in inlineformset, extra option by default, is 3.

Try this :

```
inlineformset_factory(Client, ClientData, fields=[
    'language',
    'type',
],
extra=1)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/models/#inlineformset-factory